# Pass dictionary inside dictionary to an API python

Tags: python

I want to pass the data which is in dictionary *phases* to the dictionary *data*. However, I'm not getting the format I should pass.

```
def create_flow_and_phases(request):

    phases = {
        "name": 'phase name',
        "description": 'phase description',
        "sequence_number": 1,
        "precedents": ''
    }


    data = {
        "name": request.POST['new_flow_name'],
        "description": request.POST['flow_description'],
        "category": request.POST['select_category'],
        "precedents": '',
        "users": request.session['user_pk'],
        "phases": phases
    }

    # Making a POST request to save flow_and_phases
    url = API_HOST + "/api/flows/save_flow_and_phases/"

    answer = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + request.session['user_token']})

    if not answer.ok:
        raise Exception("An error occurred while creating flow.")
```

However, by insomnia with the API format indicated below it works.

API format:

```
{
  "name": "flow name",
  "description": "flow description",
  "category": 2,
  "precedents": [3, 2],
  "users": [1],
  "phases": [
         {
            "name": "phase name",
            "description": "phase description",
            "sequence_number": 1,
            "precedents": []
         }
    ]
}
```

I just have to settle how to pass dictionary *phases* to dictionary *data*. The rest is working fine. Even if I pass phases = '', it works too.

So, how to pass dictionary *phases* inside dictionary *data* in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `phases` argument expect a `List` of `Dict`.

Your code could be:

```py
def create_flow_and_phases(request):

    phases = {
        "name": 'phase name',
        "description": 'phase description',
        "sequence_number": 1,
        "precedents": []
    }


    data = {
        "name": request.POST['new_flow_name'],
        "description": request.POST['flow_description'],
        "category": request.POST['select_category'],
        "precedents": '',
        "users": request.session['user_pk'],
        "phases": [phases] # <-- Making it a single item listwith dict
    }

    # Making a POST request to save flow_and_phases
    url = API_HOST + "/api/flows/save_flow_and_phases/"

    answer = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + request.session['user_token']})

    answer.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: An error occurred while creating flow. I don't know why it's not accepted.

Comment: You would like to print out the status code to have a more detailed description of the error. Also, you could also try to change `precedents` to list. (editing the answer)

Comment: I'm not sure about the problem. It's giving me the exception ----  if not answer.ok:
        raise Exception("An error occurred while creating flow.")